# Modifying the data of an array vs seq and passing the address of an array vs seq to asyncnet proc `send`

Tags: nim-lang

I've been working on a server that expects data to be received through a buffer. I have an object which is defined like this and some procedures that modify the buffer in it:

```
Packet* = ref object
  buf*: seq[int8]
  #buf*: array[0..4096, int8]
  pos*: int

proc newPacket*(size: int): Packet =
  result = Packet(buf: newSeq[int8](size))
  #result = Packet()

proc sendPacket*(s: AsyncSocket, p: Packet) =
  aSyncCheck s.send(addr(p.buf), p.pos)
```

Now the reason I have two lines commented is because that was the code I originally used, but creating an object that initialises an array with 4096 elements every time probably wasn't very good for performance. However, it works and the seq[int8] version does not.

The strange thing is though, my current code will work perfectly fine if I use the old static buffer `buf*: array[0..4096, int8]`. In `sendPacket`, I have made sure to check the data contained in the buffer to make sure both the array and seq[int8] versions are equal, and they are. (Or at least appear to be). In other words, if I were to do `var p = createPacket(17)` and write to `p.buf` with exactly 17 bytes, the values of the elements appear to be the same in both versions.

So despite the data appearing to be the same in both versions, I get a different result when calling `send` when passing the address of the buffer.

In case it matters, the data would be read like this:

```
result = p.buf[p.pos]
inc(p.pos)
```

And written to like this:

```
p.buf[p.pos] = cast[int8](value)
inc(p.pos)
```

Just a few things I've looked into, which were probably unrelated to my problem anyway: I looked at `GC_ref` and `GC_unref` which had no effect on my problem and also looked at maybe trying to use `alloc0` where buf is defined as `pointer` but I couldn't seem to access the data of that pointer and that probably isn't what I should be doing in the first place. Also if I do `var data = p.buf` and pass the addr of `data` instead, I get a different result, but still not the intended one.

So I guess what I want to get to the bottom of is:

1. Why does `send` work perfectly fine when I use `array[0..4096, int8]` but not `seq[int8]` which is initialised with `newSeq`, even when they appear to contain the same data?
2. Does my current layout for receiving and writing data even make sense in a language like Nim (or any language for that matter)? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order not to initialize the array you can use the `noinit` pragma like this:

```
buf* {.noinit.}: array[0..4096, int8]
```

You are probably taking the pointer to the seq, not the pointer to the data inside the seq, so try using `addr(p.buf[0])`.

A `pos` field is useless if you are using the `seq` version since you have `p.buf.len` already, but you probably know that already and just left it in for the array. If you want to use the `seq` and expect large packets, make sure to use `newSeqOfCap` to only allocate the memory once.

Also, your array is 1 byte too big, it goes from 0 to 4096 inclusively! Instead you can use `[0..4095, int8]` or just `[4096, int8]`.

Personally I would prefer to use a uint8 type inside of buf, so that you can just put in values from 0 to 255 instead of -128 to 127

Using a seq inside of a ref object means you have two layers of indirection when accessing `buf`, as well as two objects that the GC will have to clean up. You could just make `Packet` an alias for `seq[uint8]` (without ref): `type Packet* = seq[uint8]`. Or you can use the array version if you want to store some more data inside the `Packet` later on.