Use openssl and RSA encryption in nim
I want to use openssl for RSA encryption in nim however pointer types in nim are causing me problems. Currently I have this code:
import openssl

var publicRsa: PRSA
var privateRsa: PRSA
let publicKeyStr: string = readAll(open("keys/public.pem", fmRead))
let privateKeyStr: string = readAll(open("keys/private.pem", fmRead))
publicRsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(BIO_new_mem_buf(addr publicKeyStr[0], -1), publicRsa.addr, nil, nil)
privateRsa = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(BIO_new_mem_buf(addr privateKeyStr[0], -1), privateRsa.addr, nil, nil)

if publicRsa.isNil():
    echo "ERROR: Could not load PUBLIC KEY!"
    echo ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nil)
if privateRsa.isNil():
    echo "ERROR: Could not load PRIVATE KEY!"
    echo ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nil)


let msg: string = "Hello World!"
var res: ptr uint8
let lenRes: cint = RSA_public_encrypt((cint)12, cast[ptr uint8](addr msg[0]), res, publicRsa, RSA_NO_PADDING)

var decRes: ptr uint8
let lenDecRes: cint = RSA_private_decrypt(lenRes, res, decRes, privateRsa, RSA_NO_PADDING)

I don't get a compile error but when I run it I get SIGSEGV: Illegal storage access. (Attempt to read from nil?) for the line let lenDecRes: cint = RSA_private_decrypt(lenRes, res, decRes, privateRsa, RSA_NO_PADDING).
I know it is probably because I need to allocate memory for var res: ptr uint8 and var decRes: ptr uint8 but I don't know how.
Also the decryption result it a ptr uint8 and I have no idea how to convert it to a string so I can check if the decryption result is the same as the encryption input.
I am a nim beginner so it might be obvious mistake however even after searching for a long time I didn't manage to find an answer.
I wanted to make a c++ library that simplifies the openssl stuff but that would have been too much work and there must be a way to do it in nim.

Take a look here. Furthermore, if you do not use implicit padding (RSA_NO_PADDING), you must explicitly pad to the key size. It is therefore more convenient to apply a padding, e.g. RSA_PKCS1_PADDING (note, a padding is required for security reasons).

Could you create an uninitialized array first? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874472/modifying-the-data-of-an-array-vs-seq-and-passing-the-address-of-an-array-vs-seq/45874949#45874949

@RichardHeap I tried using your suggestion however I don't know what size the array needs to be and also I got a SIGSEGV: Illegal storage access. when I tried to use this to get the pointer cast[ptr uint8](addr(res[0])) (I also changed the padding to RSA_PKCS1_PADDING )
